How to demonstrate the form of the FLRW metric from homogeneity and isotropy?
In most introductions to the standard cosmological model, the metric of FLRW is stated to be corresponding to:
$$ds^2 = -c^{2}dt^2+a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$$
which means (if I'm not mistaken) for the metric tensor:
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
-c^2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{11} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{12} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{13} \\
0 & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{21} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{22} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{23} \\
0 & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{31} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{32} & a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{33} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
This is often a statement, given as evident, and I couldn't find a rigorous demonstration from first principles (even if the demonstration is simple) of why the only possible form of the metric given homogeneity and isotropy is the one above.
In practice there are two subquestions:

Why the non-diagonal terms mixing time and space (first column, first row) can only be equal to $0$? (a demonstration showing that if they are non-zero then it cannot be homogeneous and isotropic would be fine)
Why $a^{2}\left(t\right)\gamma_{ij}$ is the most general possible form for the spatial part?


Do you understand the meaning of the metric tensor in terms of the inner products of tetrads? If so, it is evident that the terms mixing space and time are zero, because otherwise,  there would be a non-zero shift vector.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Is there an equivalent contradiction using the standard formalism and not the tetrad formalism?

Can you re-phrase question 2 ?

Rotational Symmetry and Isotropy
Isotropy means that the universe looks the same in all directions from any given point. Mathematically, this implies that the metric should be invariant under rotations. If you rotate your coordinate system, the metric should retain the same form.
For example, in 3-dimensional space, a rotation might mix the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-coordinates, but the metric should remain the same in structure after this rotation if the space is isotropic.
Non-Diagonal Term $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$
Consider the presence of a term like $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$ in the metric:
$ds^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + 2 f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1 + g_{ij}(t, \vec{x}) \, dx^i \, dx^j.$
This term explicitly links the time differential $dt$ with the spatial differential $dx^1$ (the differential in the $x$-direction). The function $f_1(t, \vec{x})$ could vary with both time and spatial coordinates.
Breaking Rotational Symmetry

Preferred Direction:

The presence of $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$ introduces a special relationship between time $t$ and the $x$-direction (or $x^1$). This means that time evolution is somehow different when you move along the $x$-axis compared to the other spatial directions ($y$ or $z$).
In an isotropic universe, no direction should be special. All spatial directions should be treated equally by the metric. However, the term $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$ singles out the $x$-direction, making it different from, say, the $y$ or $z$ directions.


Effect of Rotation:

Imagine you rotate your coordinate system, say around the $z$-axis. Under such a rotation, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates get mixed. For instance, after a rotation by 90 degrees, the new $x'$-axis would align with the original $y$-axis, and the new $y'$-axis would align with the original $x$-axis.
If you started with a metric containing $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$, after this rotation, you would expect similar terms involving $dt \, dy$ in the metric. However, if the original metric had a special term only in the $x$-direction, this structure changes under rotation, violating isotropy. The metric would no longer look the same after rotation, meaning the universe would appear different when viewed in different directions.



Conclusion
The non-diagonal term $f_1(t, \vec{x}) \, dt \, dx^1$ breaks isotropy because it establishes a special relationship between time and the $x$-direction, making the $x$-axis different from the other spatial directions. In an isotropic universe, no direction should be distinguished, and the metric must be invariant under rotations. Therefore, to preserve isotropy, such non-diagonal terms that mix time and space must be zero:
$f_i(t, \vec{x}) = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad i.$
This ensures that the FRW metric remains invariant under both spatial translations and rotations, preserving the symmetries of homogeneity and isotropy.
Disclaimer: I used Chatgpt...
